# Binary search tree's nodes counter

Tags: python-3.x

My code doesn't work correctly. Tell please, what l doing wrong? Thank for you attention!

```py
def Count(self):
    def counter(Root):
        if self.Root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + counter(Root.LeftChild) + counter(Root.RightChild)
    counter(self.Root)
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of Root class

Comment: sure!                                                                                                                 
class BSTNode:
 
    def __init__(self, key, val, parent):
        self.NodeKey = key
        self.NodeValue = val
        self.Parent = parent
        self.LeftChild = None
        self.RightChild = None

Answer (score 0):

Replace self.Root with Root

```
def Count(self):
    def counter(Root):
        if Root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + counter(Root.LeftChild) + counter(Root.RightChild)
    counter(self.Root)
```